# Sharepoint 2013 Search: "OR" Default Query Mode

Tags: search

It seems that the default behaviour for SharePoint 2013 is to find search result matching **EVERY** search terms. (Let's say "SHAREPOINT 2013" query will find "**SHAREPOINT 2013**", " but won't find "*SharePoint* 2010" or "Word *2013*". Dummy example)

But I need the search to find result matching **ANY** search Terms. (I need that "**SHAREPOINT 2013**" query returns "*SharePoint* 2010" and "Word *2013*". Dummy example, again)

With Fast for SharePoint 2010, there were a query option named *query string mode* that did the trick, but I could not find a equivalent for SharePoint 2013. How can I achieve this without asking my user to add "OR" clause beetween every search terms?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The default in SharePoint is ANDed terms. This is how Google and Bing work as well. The more terms you add the smaller your result set becomes. If you want to use OR you have to add OR between your keywords.